# Getting classes from variables in Java

Tags: java

I'm making a small (for fun) game where virtual robots fight each other. I have an array of names of the classes of these robots, but I don't know how to load them. It's probably clearer in codes:

```
String[] classes={"Bot1","Bot2","Bot123"};
Object[] bots=new Object[classes.length];

for(int i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
  bots[i]=UnknownFunction(classes[i]);
}
```

Additional details:

```
package Arena;

public class Bot {
    public void main(String args[]){

    }

    public void init(){
        System.out.print("Loaded");
    }
}
```

In the main file:

```
bot=Class.forName("Arena.Bot").newInstance();
bot.init();
```

Comment: Do you want to get to a `Class` object like the one you get from `String.class` or do you want an instance of that class like in `new String()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Class.forName()` method to load your class, and then `newInstance()` method to instantiate them. Assuming that you have a `0-arg constructor` in them: -

```
bots[i] = Class.forName(classes[i]).newInstance();
```

Also note that, those class names has to be `fully qualified` names.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I get the fully qualified names?

Comment: @Linksku.. That you would have to give. Fully qualified class names means `package.subpackage.classname`. For e.g: - `pkg1.YourClass`.

Comment: I think I've managed to load the classes (try/catch does not return any errors), but I'm unable to run any methods in the classes. I always get "The method init() is undefined for the type Object".

Comment: @Linksku.. What method are you invoking? Can you post the code? Edit your question to add it.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm trying to run init(), but it always returns an error.

Comment: Type cast your `bot` to `Bot` before invoking the method.

Comment: @Linksku.. Use `((Bot)bot).init();`

Comment: So I'll have to manually cast everything then? The reason why I used an array of strings of class names was so that I can easily change the classes I need to load. Thank you for your help regardless.

Comment: @Linksku.. To get the class name for casting, you can use `Class.forName().getName()`, and then use it instead of `Bot`. But IMO, it is a big overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] classes = {"Bot1", "Bot2", "Bot123"};
Object[] bots = new Object[classes.length];

for(int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++)
{
    bots[i] = Class.forName(classes[i]).newInstance();
}
```